# Geometry: A circle inscribed in a triangle with sides lengths of 5, 8 and 9

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

A friend of mine sent me a geometry question a while ago, but unfortunately neither of us were able to find its source. Anyways, here it is:

[image: 1]

I had attempted to solve the problem but couldn't get near the answer. However, when I drew it out in Geogebra, I found that the length of the red line was 3.

I am hoping that someone might be able to solve the question using geometric approaches or theorems. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you formulate the question?

Comment: I'm sorry but wdym by formulating the question? It is as shown in the attached picture. No additional context was provided.

Comment: Based on that and the equlateral triangle only, let $a+b=5,a+c=8,b+c=9$ so they are the distances from tangent points to the vertices, is the distance the harmonic mean of $a,b,c$?

Comment: Does the line containing the red segment meet the base of the triangle at the tangent point of the incircle?

Comment: @nickgard yes, it does. It would be unsolvable otherwise.

Comment: @Empy2 for some reason that works out to be exactly 3, which is the actual length of the red line. Idk if this somehow relates to the problem or not. I'd appreciate if you could provide more context on whether it correlates with the problem or not, and if so why?.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it, but have some questions.  If you use the right-hand vertex for the dotted lines instead, is it still 3?  Are the red line's endpoints the same as before?  Does the harmonic formula work for a different triangle?

Comment: Since you claim to have drawn it in Geogebra, how did you know where to position the end-points of the dotted lines? Especially the one touching the red line? That seems like an arbitrary choice, unless you had some information about it which you forgot to mention in the question?

Comment: @Gokuカカロット I gather from the diagram that you must join a vertex with the opposite tangency point (line a), draw the diameter perpendicular to that line, and connect one of the other vertices with the endpoints of that diameter to find the intersection of the lines with a.

Comment: And the "harmonic mean" has nothing to do with the solution, because starting from another vertex the result changes. Looks like the red distance is the same as the distance from the starting vertex to one of the nearest tangency points.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca You may be right. Doing this gives red line=3 on GeoGebra. But OP needs to mention this detail right now otherwise this question is missing some key details

Comment: In general, the segment is congruent to the tangent segment(s) from the top vertex to the incircle. In the case at hand, the length of the segments is calculated as $\frac12(9+5-8)=3$. (I found the general result with a bit of ugly, *Mathematica*-assisted coordinate bashing.)

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I can't sketch the general theorem you mention: since $AD$, $AE$ intersect $AC$ at $A$, how can they intersect $AC$ again at $F$ and $G$?

Comment: @EdwardPorcella You are right: there is a typo in my comment above, here's the correct statement. 
Given an angle of vertex  and a circle tangent to the angle at  and , take any point  on ray  and draw diameter  perpendicular to . If lines ,  intersect  at  and , then =.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a proof of the general result that the target segment is congruent to the tangent segment from the "top" vertex. In the problem at hand, the length is calculated as $\frac12(9+5-8) = 3$.

---

Let $\triangle ABC$ have incircle $\bigcirc I$ of radius $r$, meeting the sides of the triangle at $D$, $E$, $F$. Let $\overline{PQ}$ be the incircle diameter perpendicular to $\overline{CF}$, and let (extensions of) $\overline{AP}$ and $\overline{AQ}$ meet $\overline{CF}$ at $P'$ and $Q'$. Define
$$\alpha:=\tfrac12\angle A, \quad\theta:=\tfrac12\angle PIF, \quad a':=|AF|=|AE|, \quad c':=|CE|, \quad p':=|FP'|, \quad q':=|FQ'|$$
and note that
$$r = a'\tan\alpha \qquad |FP| = 2r\sin\theta = 2 a'\tan\alpha\sin\theta
\qquad |FQ| = 2a'\tan\alpha\cos\theta \tag1$$

[image]

A little angle chasing shows that $\angle PFA=\angle PFC=\theta$. This allows us to compute as follows:
$$\begin{align}
|\triangle AFP'| &= |\triangle AFP| + |\triangle PFP'|\\[6pt]
\to\quad
\frac12a'p'\sin2\theta &= \frac12a'|FP|\sin\theta+\frac12p'|FP|\sin\theta\\[6pt]
\to\quad
a'p'\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta &= (a'+p')\cdot2a'\tan\alpha\sin\theta\cdot \sin\theta \\[6pt]
\to\quad
p'\cos\alpha\cos\theta &= (a'+p')\sin\alpha\sin\theta \\[6pt]
\to\quad
p' &= \frac{a'\sin\alpha\sin\theta}{\cos(\alpha+\theta)} \tag1
\end{align}$$
(This seems simple enough that there *should* be a more-direct path to it.) Likewise, we have
$$|\triangle AFQ'| = |\triangle AFQ| - |\triangle QFQ'| \quad\to\quad
q' = \frac{a'\sin\alpha\cos\theta}{\sin(\alpha+\theta)} \tag2$$
Now, we make a somewhat unmotivated observation, using some cumbersome trigonometric manipulations,
$$p'-q' + a' = \frac{a'\sin2\theta}{\sin(2\alpha +2\theta)} = \frac{a'\sin \angle AFC}{\sin\angle ACF}\;\overset{\star}{=}\;|AC| = a'+c' \tag3$$
where equality $\star$ follows from applying the Law of Sines in $\triangle ACF$. We conclude $p'-q'=c'$. $\square$

---

**Note 1.** The construction is actually symmetric in vertices $A$ and $B$. One can show that $\overline{BP}$ and $\overline{BQ}$ meet $\overline{CF}$ in $Q'$ and $P'$, yielding the same target segment.

**Note 2.** We can trade the cumbersome trig for the unmotivated observation $(3)$ for less-cumbersome trig distributed across *two* unmotivated observations:
$$p'+\frac12a' =\frac12 a'\, \frac{\cos(\alpha-\theta)}{\cos(\alpha+\theta)}
\qquad\qquad q'-\frac12a' = \frac12a'\,\frac{\sin(\alpha-\theta)}{\sin(\alpha+\theta)} \tag4$$
Then the calculation in $(3)$ amounts to $(p'+\frac12a')-(q'-\frac12a')$. Relations $(4)$ seem like they're trying to tell me something.

**Note 3.** We can also calculate
$$p'+q' = \frac{a' \sin2\alpha}{\sin(2\alpha + 2\theta)} = \frac{a'\sin\angle A}{\sin\angle ACF} = |CF| = p'+|CP'| \quad\to\quad q'=|CP'| \tag5$$
This implies that $\overline{P'Q'}$ is centered in $\overline{CF}$ (ie, the two segments have the same midpoint). This seems non-obvious.

Comment: (+1) Nicely set out answer that follows an even nicer diagram!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that finds "something special" for the given sides $5,8,9$. I am trying to go as much as possible geometrically into the structure, but to establish the "coincidence", some metric relations must come into play.

Here is the picture for the solution, we will compute ingredients step by step.

[image: A coincidence in the triangle with sides 8, 9, 5]

There is a lot of paint on the canvas, so let us introduce first the points and the notations one by one. The given triangle $\Delta = \Delta ABC$ has sides $a,b,c$ (opposite to the vertices $A,B,C$) of lengths $5$, $8$, $9$. Let $I$ be the incenter of $\Delta$, Its projections on the sides of lengths $a,b,c$ are $D,E,F$. We draw the line $BE$, then perpendicular on it and through $I$ the diameter $ST$. (In the picture, $S$ is on the half-plane containing $A$ w.r.t. $BE$.) We mark the intersections $X=AS\cap BE$, $Y=AT\cap BE$.

Projections of points on $AC$ are denoted by a perp upper script, so $B^\perp\in AC$ is for instance the foot of the height from $B$.

Let $S',T'$ be the intersection of the angle bisector $AI$ with the circle $\odot(I)=\odot(DEF)$.

---

Let us compute a lot of data related to the given triangle, in order to show:

> **Lemma:** (Similarity of triangles) $\color{blue}{\Delta IEA\sim \Delta EB^\perp B}$.

In the following proof we compute also ingredients not strictly needed for it.

*Proof*: The half-perimeter of $\Delta$ is $p=\frac 12(a+b+c)=\frac 12(5+8+9)=11$. The area $S$ of $\Delta$ is determined by (Heron):
$$
\begin{aligned}
S^2 &=p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)=11\cdot6\cdot3\cdot 2=11\cdot 6^2\ ,\qquad\text{ so } 
\\
S &=6\sqrt {11}\ .
\\[2mm]
&\qquad\text{ We also compute:}
\\
IE &=r=\frac Sp=\frac {6\sqrt{11}}{11}=\frac6{\sqrt{11}}\ ,\\
BB^\perp &= \frac {2S}b=\frac{12\sqrt{11}}8=\frac{3\sqrt{11}}2\ ,\\
BE^2 &= B^\perp B^2 + B^\perp E^2 =  \frac {99}4+\frac94=\frac 94(11+1)=27\ ,\\
\color{blue}{BE} &\color{blue}{=3\sqrt 3}\ ,
\\[2mm]
EA &=p-a=11-5=6\ ,\\
EC &=p-c=11-9=2\ ,\\
B^\perp C^2&=BC^2 - B^\perp B^2 = 25-\frac{99}4=\frac 14\ ,\\
B^\perp C&=\frac 12\ ,\\ 
\color{blue}{\frac{BB^\perp}{B^\perp E}}
&=\frac{3\sqrt{11}/2}{3/2}=\frac {\sqrt{11}}1
=\frac 6{6/\sqrt {11}} = \color{blue}{\frac{AE}{IE}}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The last relation is the needed proportionality.

$\square$

---

Let us denote then by $x$ the angle
$$
x
=\widehat{BAI}
=\widehat{IAE}
=\widehat{IEB}
=\widehat{EBB^\perp}\ .
$$
The complement $\bar x:=90^\circ-x$ is then the angle
$$
\bar x
=\widehat{AIE}
=\widehat{EIT}
=\widehat{ISS'}
=\widehat{ITT'}\ .
$$
In particular, $SS'\|IE\|BB^\perp\|TT'$ is the direction perpendicular to $AC$. This is the "coincidence" implemented by the choice of $a,b,c$ being $5,8,9$.

---

It is convenient to mark $S^*$, $T^*$, the mid points of the segments $SS'$ and $TT'$. So $S^*,I,T^*$ are colinear, $IS^*$ bisects $\widehat{SIS'}$, and the two built angles have measure $x$, and the same applies for $IT^*$ bisecting
$\widehat{SIS'}$. I was unable to see a short-cut to the end of the story, so i considered $S^\clubsuit,T^\clubsuit$ the intersections of the lines $ASX$, $ATY$ with the height from $B$. Now all needed lenghts can be computed in slow motion. (The computation show a symmetry w.r.t. the Galois conjugation of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt{11})$ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt{11})$ which sends $\sqrt 3\to-\sqrt 3$ - when passing from the $S$-world to the $T$-world and viceversa. Some many steps are done explicitly to convince the reader.)
$$
\begin{aligned}
AI^2 &= AE^2 + IE^2 = 6^2\left(1+\frac 1{11}\right)\ ,\\
AI &= 6\cdot\sqrt{\frac{12}{11}}= 12\cdot\sqrt{\frac{3}{11}}\ ,
\\
\frac{SS^*}{r}
&=\frac{SS*}{IS}
=\frac{IE}{IA}
=\frac{6/\sqrt{11}}{6\sqrt{12}/\sqrt{11}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{12}}\ ,
\\
\frac{IS^*}{r}
&=\frac{IS*}{IS}
=\frac{AE}{AI}
=\frac{6}{6\sqrt{12}/\sqrt{11}}=\frac {\sqrt{11}}{\sqrt{12}}\ ,
\\
SS^* &= \frac r{\sqrt{12}}= \frac 6{\sqrt{11\cdot 12}}
= \frac {\sqrt 3}{\sqrt{11}}\ ,\\
IS^* &= r\cdot\sqrt{\frac {11}{12}}= \frac 6{\sqrt{12}}=\sqrt3\ ,
\\
SS^\perp &=S^*S^\perp + SS^* = IE + SS^*
=\frac{6+\sqrt 3}{\sqrt{11}}\ ,
\\
TT^\perp &=T^*T^\perp - TT^* = IE - TT^*
=\frac{6-\sqrt 3}{\sqrt{11}}\ ,
\\
S^\clubsuit B^\perp
&=SS^\perp\cdot\frac{AB^\perp}{AS^\perp}
=\frac{6+\sqrt 3}{\sqrt{11}}\cdot\frac{8-\frac 12}{6-\sqrt 3}
=\frac{15}{22\sqrt {11}}(2\sqrt 3+1)^2\ ,\\
T^\clubsuit B^\perp
&=TT^\perp\cdot\frac{AB^\perp}{AT^\perp}
=\frac{6-\sqrt 3}{\sqrt{11}}\cdot\frac{8-\frac 12}{6+\sqrt 3}
=\frac{15}{22\sqrt {11}}(2\sqrt 3-1)^2\ ,\\
S^\clubsuit B
&= BB^\perp - S^\clubsuit B^\perp
=\frac {33}{2\sqrt{11}} - \frac{15}{22\sqrt {11}}(2\sqrt 3+1)^2
=\frac 1{22\sqrt {11}}12(2-\sqrt3)(2\sqrt 3+1)^2\ ,
\\
T^\clubsuit B
&= BB^\perp - T^\clubsuit B^\perp
=\frac {33}{2\sqrt{11}} - \frac{15}{22\sqrt {11}}(2\sqrt 3-1)^2
=\frac 1{22\sqrt {11}}12(2+\sqrt3)(2\sqrt 3-1)^2\ ,
\\[3mm]
1&=
\frac{XB}{XE}\cdot
\frac{AE}{AB^\perp}\cdot
\frac{S^\clubsuit B^\perp}{S^\clubsuit B}\ ,
\qquad\text{ (Menelaus for $\Delta BEB^\perp$ with secant line $AXS^\clubsuit$)}
\\
\frac{XE}{XB}&=
\frac{AE}{AB^\perp}\cdot
\frac{S^\clubsuit B^\perp}{S^\clubsuit B}
=
\frac{6}{15/2}\cdot
\frac{15}{12(2-\sqrt3)}
=\frac 1{2-\sqrt3}
=\frac{2+\sqrt 3}1\ ,
\\[2mm]
\frac{XE}{BE}&=
\frac{2+\sqrt 3}{3+\sqrt 3}=\frac 16(3+\sqrt3)\ ,
\\
\frac{YE}{BE}&
=\frac 16(3-\sqrt3)\ ,
\\
\frac{XY}{BE}&
=\frac 16\Big( \ (3+\sqrt3) - (3-\sqrt3)\ \Big)
=\frac 1{\sqrt3}\ ,
\\
\color{blue}{XY}
&=
\color{blue}{BE\cdot\frac 1{\sqrt 3}
=3\sqrt 3\cdot\frac 1{\sqrt 3}
=\boxed{3}\ .
}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

A final note:

A condition to have $\color{blue}{\Delta IEA\sim \Delta EB^\perp B}$
for a triangle with sides $a,b,c$ is
$$
(2a + b - 2c)(a + 3b - 3c) = 0\ .
$$
This is obtained by algebraic manipulations starting from
$\displaystyle\frac r{p-a}=\frac{(p-c)-\sqrt{a^2-h_B^2}}{h_B}$.

However some inequalities have to hold, too, they are $a+c<2b$ and $ab>2S$.

The values of $a,b,c$ from the problem, $5,8,9$ satisfy $2a+b=2c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Draw Circumcircle of triangle ABC (A top B left C right) with radius R and center at O.We have:

$P=\frac{5+8+9}2$

$S=\sqrt{p(p-5)(p-8)(p-9)}$

$R=\frac{5\times 8\times 9}{4 S}\approx 4.5$

Mark center of circumscribed circle as $O_1$ with radius r.

$r=\frac S p\approx 1.8$

Accurate drawing shows that a circle passing points J and F (J if top point of required segment and F is it's bottom) and tangent to AC has center $O_2$ at distance equal to $OO_1$. This circle has equal radius to that of circumscribed circle r. Due to Euler's theorem:

$(OO_1)^2=R(R-2r)\approx 2$

Draw perpendiculars  $O_1H$ and $O_2G$ to side AC. The distance between $ O_2$ and JF i.e  $O_2 I\approx GH\approx 0.9$. $O_2F=r\approx 1.8$ , we have:

$JF=2\times \sqrt{1.8^2-0.9^2}\approx 2\times 1.5=3$

Note: I can not attach my figure due to the site's restriction for me. I can post the figure if I have an address.